# Best database choice for my Cordova application

Tags: jquery, database, angularjs, cordova

I am working on an Cordova application (for Android and iPhone) which requires to store offline actions and then sync those actions to server when internet becomes available. Actually I am new to Cordova (PhoneGap). I am using JQuery and AngularJS for performing other actions. Now my question is which would be the best Database choice in my case?

I know about LocalStorage but that will not meet my needs. Second one is WebSQL. I have seen its specification page. They are no longer maintaining this framework. IndexedDB I guess is only for Windows phone and Blackberry phones. There may be other big ones that I don't know. So I need your suggestions for possible options.

Comment: What is your actual question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have two database for you. First one is I'm using for almost over a year. Didn't face any issue. [Brodysoft SQL wrapper plugin](https://github.com/brodysoft/Cordova-SQLitePlugin) It's use is just like web sql.

```
function onDeviceReady() {
  var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: "my.db"});
  // ...
}
```

I didn't use the second one but saw the reference in SO. Read that it's very efficient. [HTML5SQL](http://html5sql.com/)

```
$.get('Setup-Tables.SQL',function(sqlStatements){
    html5sql.process(
        //This is the text data from the SQL file you retrieved
        sqlStatements,
        function(){
            // After all statements are processed this function
            //   will be called.
        },
        function(error){
            // Handle any errors here
        }
    );
});
```

Between this two choice has to be yours.

Comment: ok, I am gonna use Brodysoft SQL wrapper plugin. It seems promising to me. Will need more of your support in future if I stuck somewhere. :)

Comment: @KhawarRaza agreed. after reading through the docs and seeing recent commits looks like this project is fairing well. What has been your experience thus far?

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest to use MongoDB.
MongoDB is a document database that provides high performance, high availability, and easy scalability.
A database holds a set of collections.
 A collection holds a set of documents. A document is a set of key-value pairs (JSON object).

Comment: How would you use MongoDB while offline?

Comment: What is the storage limit?